# Спешиалти, спешелти или другие варианты?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, переводы, транскрипция, транслитерация

Словари не фиксируют написание слова *спешиалти* (мне этот вариант наиболее близок, однако хотелось бы услышать и другие мнения). Речь идёт о категории кофейного зерна высокого качества. Есть такие варианты написания:

Транслитерация: спешиалти.

Транскрипция: спешелти.

Нечто промежуточное: спешалти (наименее, на мой взгляд, пригодный  способ написания. Кроме того, нечётко отражает как орфоэпическую, так и орфографическую норму).

Каким способом перевода, по вашему мнению, предпочтительней руководствоваться?

Comment: JKlen, насчёт произношения — да, верно, однако это сочетание согласных [шлт] меня смущает. И вообще — произнесите слово — звук [ш] всё равно звучит как некий слогообразующий, так что уместнее, возможно, поставить после него гласный.

Comment: Также рассматриваю возможность сохранения оригинального начертания: кофе specialty, однако тут возникает замечание. Specialty уже нельзя назвать экзотизмом, он пусть и не занял прочную позицию на рынке, но всё же стал довольно известным потребителю. Соответственно, термин требует графического освоения. А как Вы считаете?

Comment: JKlen, а мне кажется, немного не тот звук. Если мы произносим в английской речи, то [ə] ещё есть шанс услышать. Читая транскрибированный вариант в русскоязычном тексте, каждый второй произнесёт грубо [шлт], ещё и удивится, что за нетипичное звукосочетание.